# How to check if one field matches another in Django Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, data-cleaning, modelform

I'm trying to have my form check if the email field matches the verify_email field in  my Django form but it is not working.

My forms.py file:

```
class SignupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FormSubmission
        fields ='__all__'
        widgets = {'botcatcher': forms.HiddenInput()}

        def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super().clean()
            email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
            vmail = self.cleaned_data.get('verify_email')

            if email != vmail:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("Emails must 
                match"), code="invalid")
            return cleaned_data
```

My model.py file:

```
class FormSubmission(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    email = models.EmailField(unique= False)
    verify_email = models.EmailField(unique = False)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    botcatcher = models.CharField(max_length= 1, blank=True, 
    validators=[validators.MaxLengthValidator(0)])


    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s"% (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

It was my indentation for the def clean function.